# Create Microsoft Report in C# with SQLite DB

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013, report, reportviewer

I am developing a Win Forms Application with **C#.NET, VS 2013, and SQLite**. I want to make a **Report with Microsoft Report Viewer (rdlc)**, but I don't know How to make a Data Source with Wizard, because of in Wizard step doesn't **SQLite data provider**.

[image]

**How to I can make a Data Source and Report with SQLite ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saeed, you need to download and install a SQLite data provider.  Either ODBC or the .NET provider.  I'd recommend the ODBC driver for the scenario you describe so you may use the  Microsoft Report Viewer tool.

The ODBC driver is available here:
http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

Comment: It was a problem, any time will reconnect to DB, why? @Chris Townsend

Comment: @SaeedRahmani , what do you mean? Please give me a little more info.  A problem with the ODBC driver - or what? I am a SQLite fan but have not had the best experience with it on Windows.  On Linux, flawless.  On Windows, not so much but I continue to use it because I like it better than Access.  You'd need to post a lot more about the problem you are having to get any further help.

Comment: I create my question exactly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873296/no-such-table-in-c-sharp-with-sqlite