# No such Table in C# with SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, report, database-connection, connection-string

I want to make a Report with Microsoft Report Viewer in C# with SQLite DB, I am using [SQLite ODBC Driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) and when I make DataSet and Data Source to report, it has such Error:

**Additional information: ERROR [HY000] no such table: Fuel (1)**

but I have this Table and I have Connection to SQLite DB.

**Here is Error:**

[image]

**and I have Dataset and Database connection:**

[image]

**But When I want to load data from Table it retries to connect:**

[image]

---

> Anytime to work with Database it wants to connect to DB again.

---

When I want show Table date it was retry to connect:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a problem when you make a **32bit application** on **64bit OS**.

This is the notice in [SQLite ODBC Driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/), need install 64 bit and 32 bit.

[image]